# Pimcore Twig Templating Helpers set type="text/javascript"

Tags: javascript, twig, pimcore-v5

I have done the following in pimcore, using Twig instead of PHP;

```
{% do pimcore_head_script().appendFile(asset('static/js/page.min.js')) %}
```

which results in the following when I "view source".

```
<script src="/static/js/page.min.js"></script>
```

Now, I need to make the add type="text/javascript" to this portion, so that it looks like this;

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/page.min.js"></script>
```

However, I do not know how to do it. There isnt much documentation on how to do via Twig syntax. I have tried many iterations, but to no avail.

Comment: Why would you need to append that? Adding the `type` of the script is unnecessary. As seen [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-type) it is encouraged not to specify the type in `HTML5`

Comment: i have discovered that some of my jquery are not functioning without it.

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

As described in [pimcore 10 documentation](https://pimcore.com/docs/pimcore/current/Development_Documentation/MVC/Template/Template_Extensions/HeadScript.html), this should be possible:

```
{% do pimcore_head_script().appendFile(
    '/js/prototype.js',
    'text/javascript',
    {conditional: 'lt IE 11'}
%}
```